# Monitor API Gateway APIs based on API key

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-key, aws-api-gateway

How can I monitor my Amazon API Gateway APIs API key wise?

Currently it is showing data for all API keys, but I want to display API calls, 5xx errors, 4xx errors etc for particular API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking at monitoring the API on `X-Api-Key` header level, it looks like this is currently not possible. I'm guessing you'd have to do it yourself on the application layer, which should be relatively easy if you're using `Lambda`. Your question brings up another question: Does it really make sense to monitor individual API keys when errors are associated with particular API deployment/version?

If you'd like to monitor per-user use, you need to make use of `IAM` credentials with your API and `CloudTrail` to monitor requests made with specific credentials. You can find more info on the [API Gateway CloudTrail integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail.html) page.

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail.html

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming he's referring to the `API Key` used in the `X-Api-Key` header.

Comment: That isn't included in `requestParameters` in the log entries?

Comment: I didn't test the `CloudTrail` integration yet so I'm not sure if it logs headers. Thanks for the suggestion, I expanded my answer with it.

Comment: @napalm Actually I will create different API key for different third party developers. And they will call our Amazon API Gateway APIs using given API key and I want to show them their total API calls and failed calls (e.g. 4xx, 5xx) via dashboard. So using your given details, if I want to show dashboard at real-time, I have to fetch log every time and parse it and it would be very time consuming process. That's why I asked is there any easy API or method available for filtering data by API key?

Comment: `CloudTrail` would have to support it if `X-Api-Key` is being logged there. I think you might have to build your own solution.

Comment: @napalm  I also checked in log file generated by CloudTrail in S3 bucket, but no API key or parameters are there.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway doesn't (yet) offer first-class support for API Key metrics. As @kixorz mentioned, you could implement this in the application layer for the time being (for example using Lambda and CloudWatch).