# Monitoring access to AWS API Gateway resources using api-keys

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-api-gateway

I have built a gateway (using aws api gateway) in front of my rest api.  I want to monitor the usage of resources on that api using the api-keys generated by api gateway.  By 'usage' I mean which resources were requested and served to clients associated with an api key.  Amazon claims that cloudtrail can be used to track gateway requests but the x-api-key header does not show up in cloudtrail logs.  Has amazon provided an idiomatic way of doing this?  Has anyone implemented this functionality in a custom manner?  It seems reasonable that this functionality should be built in, however I cannot find how to do this anywhere.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitor API Gateway APIs based on API key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313393/monitor-api-gateway-apis-based-on-api-key)

Comment: Thanks.  Api gateway changes so fast because it's a new technology I thought there might've been an updated solution.  I see that there's probably not