# AWS API Gateway: programmatically generating API keys

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a project using Amazon API Gateway and wonder if there's a way through the AWS SDK or over REST to programmatically create API keys for monitoring requests:

[AWS API Gateway FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/)

[API Key docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/api-key/)

It seems like they want you to use a custom authenticator for security purposes - over depending on an AWS API key. Using an application user for IAM I was thinking my application user would make the actual requests with the AWS IAM key and secret key then add on a user's particular API key for request counts / rate limiting.

Does this approach make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: It appears there's a manualw ay to do this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html But i haven't found a way to automate this.

Comment: Based on this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313393/monitor-api-gateway-apis-based-on-api-key maybe this just isn't supported yet?

Answer (score 4):

Creating an API key is buried in the AWS SDK for [API Gateway](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key)

Upon last reading I believe stages are limited to 10,000 API Keys / account so this won't scale at infimum.

[create_api_key for API Gateway](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key)

Comment: By default, 500 API keys per account/region.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have 2 ways to create AWS Gateway API keys programmatically via:

- [AWS CLi](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli)
- [Api Gateway Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_CreateApiKey.html) using [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/APIGateway/NAPIGateway.html)

sample code:

```
//Create api key
var apiGatewayClient = new AmazonAPIGatewayClient();
await apiGatewayClient.CreateApiKeyAsync(new CreateApiKeyRequest() { Name = apiKey }));

//Add api key to usage plan
var p = new CreateUsagePlanKeyRequest() { UsagePlanId = usagePlanId, KeyId = apiGatewayClient.Id, KeyType = "API_KEY" };
await apiGatewayClient.CreateUsagePlanKeyAsync(p);
```